# angular 2 routing 3.0.0-rc.2 repeating route

Tags: angular

I'm having some problems with the routing in my angular 2 application for example i'm in

> https://www.url.com/index

and if I reload the page the url seems like this

> https://www.url.com/index/index

and if I do it again

> https://www.url.com/index/index/index

and so on

The version i'm using is "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2"

my **app.routing.ts** seems like this

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { subprocessesComponent } from './Subprocesses.component';
import { moduleTermsComponent }   from './moduleTerms.component';
import { retailProcessesComponent } from './retailProcesses.Component';
import { seeDocTestComponent } from './seeDocTest.component';

//import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
//import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/index',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'index',
        component: moduleTermsComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'processes/:id',
        component: retailProcessesComponent
    },    
    {
        path: 'processes/subprocesses/:id',
        component: subprocessesComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'seeDocs',
        component: seeDocTestComponent
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

By the way i'm using webpack for bundle my app, so in my index.html i've the script     `<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/app.bundle.js"></script>`

If anybody knows what's happening or if i'm doing something wrong i'll appreciate some help with this

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

My **app.module.ts** look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { moduleTermsComponent } from './moduleTerms.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { processListComponent } from './processesList.component';
import { retailProcessesComponent } from './retailProcesses.Component';
import { subProcessItemsComponent } from './subProcessItems.component';
import { subprocessesComponent} from './Subprocesses.component';
import { seeDocTestComponent } from './seeDocTest.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {AccordionModule} from "ng2-accordion";

import { serviceTerms } from './serviceTerms.service'; 
import { MyLogger } from './MyLogger';
import { routing } from './app.routing';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        AccordionModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        moduleTermsComponent,
        AppComponent,
        retailProcessesComponent,
        processListComponent,
        subprocessesComponent,
        subProcessItemsComponent,
        seeDocTestComponent
        //PaginatePipe
    ],
    providers: [serviceTerms],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
```

to providers of `AppModule`

Comment: hi @Günter Zöchbauer thanks for the replay, i updated my question with my app.module.ts, can you tell me please where should i add that?

Comment: To providers, Next to `serviceTerms`. Not sure if it fixes your issue.

Comment: i imported APP_BASE_HREF like so: import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common'; and then put it into providers like this     providers: [serviceTerms, { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }] and it gives me this errors : **error TS2345: Argument of type '{ provide: any; useValue: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ExtraOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'provide' does not exist in type 'ExtraOptions'.** and **error TS2304: Cannot find name 'APP_BASE_HREF'.**